# How to change string resource xml values in Android programatically?

Tags: xml, android, string, resources

Is there any possibility to Edit String.xml values in Android? Please suggest me the possible ways. 
 I want to provide Enable/Disable option for my App. To accomplish this I can use SQLite database. But I doesn't like to Use DB for a single variable value.  
Thanks in Advance. 
 With Regards,  
Raghavendra K.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to edit String.xml directly.  However there is a middle ground, look into using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  Those are great when you just have a couple values to store and don't feel like dealing with a full database.