# TouchListView is not working when parent activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I'm using a `TouchListView` by CommonWare and  so far it's working fine, But it fails in the following case:

- `activity A` has a TouchListView and button to add an item , now when i click over a button,
- `activity B` opens up and once the user choose the item i am calling `finish` to end      `activity B`
- and it comes back to `activity A`.

Now here drag n drop in `TouchListView` doesn't work I mean items are getting dragged but not able to be placed where a user wants, I tried a lot but could not find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're doing some setup in onCreate() that's not getting called when you return to Activity A because you're entering it the 2nd (and subsequent) time(s) via onResume().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

[image]

```
BaseAdapter adapter;
List<myStuff> stuffs;

if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new BaseAdapter()
    if (stuffs == null) {
        stuffs = new List<myStuff>();
    }
}
```

You're going to need to do something like that and add List to your savedInstanceState bundle in onSaveInstanceState() then dig it out when the activity restarts.

Comment: Well if i put new Adapter create code i.e. `adapter=new IconicAdapter(this,R.layout.contact_listview,contactList);` then only things work well , but every time creating a new Adapter isn't good right ?

Comment: If check it for null.  If it's not null create it.  In onPause() you probably need to be putting your data into the bundle too ;)

Comment: Well it never gets `NULL` n it only works when i create it everytime , i wondered my other listviews works fine with this TouchListView just acting weirdly.