# Android: Edit strings.xml inside java code

Tags: android, string

I was wondering if it was possible to edit a string saved in the strings.xml file. If you can then how do you do this. So far I cannot see that you can but I am new to android.

Comment: Its not possible, Android .apk file is Read-Only..

Comment: No you can't. Read this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069671/how-to-change-string-resource-xml-values-in-android-programatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069671/how-to-change-string-resource-xml-values-in-android-programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. You can't edit your res folder. The data what you have in your apk file is read only. You can't edit it on the go.